# mysql hierarchical sql query having unordered parentid

Tags: mysql

Hello Experts i have node table which has nodeid and parentid columns and i trying to get list of all nodes in such a way that parent nodes are listed before child nodes .

In this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52009d/8/0) example i am not getting node id 20,21 as result

Query i have used is

```
select  nodeid,parentid from    
(select * from node 
order by parentid, nodeid) channel_sorted,    
(select @pv := '0') initialisation  
where   find_in_set(parentid, @pv)  and   length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', nodeid))
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: **side note:**  When it comes to hierarchical storage, parent row always comes before child. Meaning, `parent_id` cannot exist without it existing itself. In your case, how did you end up with `(19, 'categor19', 2296)` ? You are facing this issue because of a poor design. You may still achieve this with PHP as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359864/php-usort-for-string-hierarchy/).

Comment: 1 0
4 1
5 1
2296 4
19 2296 
20 19 
21 19

Comment: Yes @vivek_23, yes that's how the data is , i need to create parent-node before child node , but query isn't returning in order that i am expecting.  Isn't there a way in mysql to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, I've tried it on sqlfiddle example you mentioned and it worked:

```
SET @position := 0;
select nodeid,parentid from
  (select nodeid,node.parentid from
     (select distinct parentid,(@position := @position + 1) s
         from node) as t inner join node on t.parentid=node.nodeid
     order by s) as f

union

select nodeid,parentid
from node
where nodeid not in (select parentid from node);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't respect `parent nodes are listed before child nodes`.

Comment: `order by` becomes irrelevant actually. [See the fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7c602/1). It doesn't yield as expected.

Comment: Try the edited version of the answer, I think this is what you wanted.

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Check the order of `19` and `2296`.

Comment: Thanks @Abdo20293 , but as a result node 19 is coming after child nodes (20,21), whereas i am looking to get 1st parentnode then child node

Comment: With updated query you provided , node 2296 is coming after node 19 ,whereas 2296 is parent of 19

Comment: @Vijay try this one.

Comment: Thanks but node 4 is coming after 2296

Comment: You are welcome, that's because it's inserted this way in the table.
The poor design of the table is making the solution to what you want complicated, as @vivek_23 mentioned their shouldn't be a child node inserted in table before it's parent node.